# Как из приложения asp.net core 3.1 запустить консольное приложение из другой сборки

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, exe

Имеется два приложения. Первое - консольное, второе - сервер на asp.net core 3.1. Как мне при запуске сервера запускать первое приложение?

Startup.cs

```
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        InitConsoleApp();
    }

private static void InitConsoleApp()
{
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("./bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/CoolParking.Bl.exe");
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        Process.Start(startInfo);
}
```

Comment: В отдельном процессе запускайте.

Comment: В Main() запускайте как процесс.

Comment: Пример кода можно?

Comment: Эти два приложения находятся в одном solution

Comment: Как вы запускаете сервер? Что делает консольное приложение?

Comment: Очень вероятно, что Вы забиваете гвозди микроскопом. Если Вам нужно по ходу работы веб-приложения выполнять в фоне какую-то задачу, то это прямое определение HostedService'а, который Вам просто нужно зарегистрировать в сервисах своего asp.net core-приложения

Comment: @Kir_Antipov у такого подхода, есть плюс в том, что приложение может ещё продолжать работать, когда экземпляр веб-службы будет остановлен, для обновления версии, например. Это мои мысли по использованию данного сценария, зачем это автору, я естественно не в курсе

Comment: @4per, обновления должны проходить быстро, так что остановка службы на пару секунд не может быть чем-то плохим. Если же остановка службы все же является чем-то плохим, значит, что-то не так с архитектурой

Comment: @Kir_Antipov как насчет длительных асинхронных пакетных заданий? Насколько я знаю обычно для них используют отдельную службу, но и её тоже надо же обновлять.

Comment: @4per, если задача является полностью независимой от веб-приложения и даже должна жить от него отдельно, то да, можно собрать службу. Но это уже самостоятельная единица, с которой и работать надо вне контекста asp.net core-решения

Answer (score 2):

Код веб-страницы и серверного элемента управления ASP.NET выполняется в контексте рабочего процесса ASP.NET на веб-сервере. При использовании метода Start на веб-странице ASP.NET или серверном элементе управления новый процесс выполняется на веб-сервере с ограниченными разрешениями. Процесс не запускается в том же контексте, что и браузер клиента, и **не имеет доступа к рабочему столу пользователя**.
Соответственно, ваше приложение CoolParking.Bl.exe запускается и должно быть видно в процессах в диспетчере задач, но оно не получит GUI, и вы его не увидите.

Опишите подробнее свою задачу, для чего вам нужно запускать из контекста рабочего процесса веб-сервера консольное приложение, и мы вместе придумаем решение.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("имя_вашего_файла.exe"); /// если у вас exe
// или
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("dotnet", "имя_вашего_файла.dll"); /// если у вас dll
```

Дополнительное чтение: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Выше представил пример запускаемого кода, но запуск не происходит и консоль другого приложения не открывается. Путь к файлу .exe правильный.

Comment: @СергейЧижик Вы указываете относительный путь? Попробуйте полный.

Comment: Ничего не меняется, если путь к файлу указывается не правильно, вылетает исключение